# SELECT INNER JOIN usando PHP foreach no DataTable

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, prepared-statement

Estou trabalhando em um CRUD utilizando DataTable onde me mostra dados de 3 tabelas relacionadas onde dessas três tabelas duas são relacionadas com uma.

No caso o código PHP é executado para fazer um fetch e mostrar os dados na tabela em questão. Ocorre que quando insiro apenas um SELECT INNER JOIN no código o campo aparece o nome ao invés do ID. Até aqui tudo bem, porém quando acrescento mais um INNER JOIN ocorre o seguinte erro:

> DataTables warning: table id=user_data - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

As 3 tabelas mencionadas são estruturadas da seguinte forma:

### Tabela tipo_ps

```
tipoID    tipo
```

### Tabela categorias

```
categoriaID    categoria
```

### E tabela users

```
id    tipo_fk    categoria_fk    nome
```

No caso a tabela users possui 2 campos Foreing Key (tipo_fk e categoria_fk) e para realizar um php foreach fetch na tabela DataTable utilizo o código abaixo:

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
$query = '';
$output = array();
$query .= "SELECT users.*, tipo_ps.tipo, categorias.categoria
FROM users
INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON users.tipo_fk = tipo_ps.tipoID (Obs.: Se eu deixar apenas este INNER JOIN tipo_ps o mesmo aparece como nome ao invés do número ID porém se eu acrescento o INNER JOIN abaixo ocorre o erro)
INNER JOIN categorias ON users.categoria_fk = categorias.categoriaID

 ";


if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= 'WHERE first_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
 $query .= 'OR last_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
 
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row["tipo"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["categoria"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["nome"];
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  $filtered_rows,
 "recordsFiltered" => get_total_all_records(),
 "data"    => $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

E na página index é executada com o seguinte código HTML:

```html
<div class="container box">
   <h1 align="center">Usuários cadastrados</h1>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <br />
    <div align="right">
     <button type="button" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add</button>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th width="20%">Tipo</th>
       <th width="20%">Categoria</th>
       <th width="20%">Nome</th>
       <th width="10%">Editar</th>
       <th width="10%">Deletar</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Como mencionado quando insiro apenas o SELECT INNER JOIN do campo tipo_fk o mesmo aparece na tabela com o nome ao invés do ID:

```
$query .= "SELECT users.*, tipo_ps.tipo, categorias.categoria
FROM users
INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON users.tipo_fk = tipo_ps.tipoID
INNER JOIN categorias ON users.categoria_fk = categorias.categoriaID
```

porém quando insiro na sequência um outro INNER JOIN relativo ao campo categoria_fk e dou um refresh na página index ocorre o erro Json:

> DataTables warning: table id=user_data - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1 ";

Como posso proceder? Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Isto é porque você está trazendo o nome do tipo quando declara no select: tipo_ps.tipo

```
$query .= "SELECT users.*, tipo_ps.tipo, categorias.categoria
FROM users
INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON users.tipo_fk = tipo_ps.tipoID
INNER JOIN categorias ON users.categoria_fk = categorias.categoriaID

 ";
```

ao invés de colocar tipo_ps.tipoID:

```
$query .= "SELECT users.*, tipo_ps.tipoID, categorias.categoria
FROM users
INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON users.tipo_fk = tipo_ps.tipoID
INNER JOIN categorias ON users.categoria_fk = categorias.categoriaID

 ";
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Luiz. Fiz a alteração conforme mencionado e me é retornado o seguinte erro: Notice: Undefined index: length in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\fetch.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined index: start in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\fetch.php fetch.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: length in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\fetch.php fetch.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: draw in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\fetch.php fetch.php on line 58
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":0,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":[]}

Comment: Quando você fez a alteração parou de dar o erro de json e deu esse erro no XAMP? Faz o diagnóstico listado nesta página: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1 e vê o que ele mostra de json por favor. Talvez seja só na tradução dos dados mesmo, mas se você quer o id realmente teria de deixar no seu select o tipoID. Volta e executa o teste de diagnóstico pra ver o que ele trazia no json.

Comment: Olá Luiz. Fiz um diagnostico e foi retornado o erro acima porém percebi que se eu fizer apenas um INNER JOIN a tabela me retorna o nome ao invés do ID:  ---> SELECT users.*, tipo_ps.tipo
FROM users
INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON users.tipo_fk = tipo_ps.tipoID ---> Porém se eu acrescentar mais um INNER JOIN nesta query a tabela não retorna valor algum.

Comment: A query executando diretamente no banco exibe os dados direitinho? Outra coisa: já tentou fazer este segundo JOIN com LEFT JOIN  ao invés de INNER JOIN? Realmente a questão é que você precisa do ID e está query tem de estar trazendo seus dados certo no banco para depois passar para a aplicação.

Comment: Agradeço pela sua atenção Luiz. Sim, quando executo esta query no MySql é retornado o resultado que gostaria de que fosse mostrado na tabela conforme esta imagem https://imgur.com/LqnrWsI porém quando tento utilizar esta mesma query dentro do código php, a tabela DataTables retorna o erro Invalid JSON response, porém se eu retirar um INNER JOIN da query por exemplo, a tabela, em apenas uma coluna, me retorna o nome do registro ao invés do ID https://imgur.com/VYCkD69. Nesse caso o erro pode estar ocorrendo no próprio código php que efetua o fetch para aparecer os resultados na tabela? Obrigado

Comment: Cara vi uma coisa agora: você definiu apenas três campos para exibição nas tags th da tabela, mas sua query retorna muito mais campos (inclusive você está retornando todos os campos da tabela users quando utiliza ```users.*```). Confere os campos e retire os que você não vai usar do retorno da sua query e vê o que acontece.